# Skipped questions coming up again in review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, vote-to-close

I've been taking my new Mjolnir and smiting some Java Duplicates by hitting the Close Review queue with a Java+Duplicate filter...however even filtering on Java there are some questions that I come to where I'm not sure whether Duplicate or Open are the correct answer as they are similar, but not completely the same or they are using libraries I'm not familiar with, or other similar reasons.

In those cases I've been pressing skip to move on to ones where I am sure...but they keep coming back again...and again...and again...I've recently just taken a best guess stab at a couple to stop them coming back but I'm really not comfortable doing that.

After I've skipped a question would it be possible to have it not show up in my review queue unless it really is the only question remaining that matches that filter?

Comment: That *is* the functionality of "Skip".  You *don't* see the same question again when you skip it.

Comment: It might be that the item comes up again if the item changes, such as gets a new close type. However this is a guess.